# Validador en un modelo - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

estoy intentando evitar que se realice la autorizacion de una practica dos veces en el mismo dia, para el mismo afiliado y el mismo prestador.
Lo que ocurre es que una autorizacion puede tener 1 o mas practicas dentro lo cual me genera el problema a la hora de hacer el validador. Lo primero que hago (que se ejecuta cuando se va a crear la autorizacion) es obtener en una variable todas las autorizaciones que tiene realizadas en el dia de hoy el afiliado, lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
authorised_today= self.authorisation.affiliate.authorisations.where(
  created_at: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.end_of_day
)
```

Si `authorised_today.present?` necesitaria verificar si dentro de esa autorizacion existe una practica igual a la que estoy intentando registrar en el momento. Lo que habia intentado era lo siguiente, pero no me funciono ya que existe el caso que mas de una practica este en una misma autorizacion.

```
  if authorised_today.present?
    unless authorised_today.items.find_by_practice(self.practice).nil?
      errors.add(t('Ya existe una practica autorizada para el dia de hoy.'))
    end
  end
```

He realizado un `byebug` de la variable `authorised_today` para ver si efectivamente me traia algun dato y si, me trae bien las autorizaciones del dia. Luego si intento realizar `authorised_today.items` me tira un error de que el metodo `items` no esta definido. Aclaro que todo esto lo estoy haciendo en el modelo de authorisation.

METODO QUE UTILIZO ACTUALMENTE EN MI MODELO PARA VALIDAR:

```
def validation_one_for_day
#authorised_today = authorisation.affiliate.authorisations.find_by(created_at: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.end_of_day)
prac_name = self.practice.name
authorised_today = authorisation.affiliate.authorisations.where({state: ["approved","pending"], created_at: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.end_of_day})
if authorised_today.present?
  #byebug
    authorised_today.each do |at|
      #byebug
      at.items.each do |ati|
        if at.items.find_by_practice_id(self.practice_id).present?
          errors.add(:base, 'Ya existe una practica autorizada o pendiente para el dia de hoy: ' + prac_name.to_s)
          #break
        end
      end
    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo del todo el problema, pero si `authorised_today` trae el resultado de un `where`, entonces vendrá como resultado un objeto del tipo `ActiveRecord_Relation`, o en otras palabras, una colección o arreglo de resultados (incluso si encuentra solo uno) y no un resultado único donde puedas acceder a sus `items`.
Desde aquí ya entra a que solo tu sabes como debería ser la lógica, pero las opciones que veo es que busques un único valor que cumpla tus criterios de búsqueda con `find_by`:

```
authorised_today = authorisation.affiliate.authorisations.find_by(
  created_at: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.end_of_day
)
# Ahora si podrías acceder a la relación, ya que es un registro único, no una colección
authorised_today.items
```

o, para el caso donde esperas múltiples registros, puedes dejar el `where` y revisar los items para c/u de ellos, con algo como:

```
if authorised_today.present?
  authorised_today.each do |at|
    next if at.items.find_by_practice(practice).nil?

    errors.add(:base, 'Ya existe una practica autorizada para el dia de hoy.')
    # Asumo que después de encontrar un caso de error no necesitas seguir
    # iterando, si no no debería ir el break
    break
  end
end
```

Comment: Me sirvio todo lo que me dijiste, tengo solo un problema, cuando hago el at.items.find_by_practice(self.practice_id) seria para una sola practica, como hago en el caso de que cargo varias practicas y necesito comparar cada una de ellas con cada items de la autorizacion?

Comment: Edite la pregunta y agregue el metodo que utilizo actualmente para validar en el modelo.